# How to create a new column "NewId" base on dictionary value in pandas dataframe using Lambda function

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I'm new to programming and I wanted to create a newId base on my dictionary values. I so several Lambda functions and it use to create new fields and it efficient to use. I tried several codes but couldn't implement it into my problem here. Any help is appreciated.

My panda's dataframe look like this

```
    ID1     ID2
76  21.0    21.0
77  21.0    11562.0
78  21.0    131241.0
79  22.0    22.0
80  22.0    11562.0
81  23.0    23.0
82  23.0    33680.0
83  23.0    131031.0
84  23.0    523376.0
```

I have a dictionary like this

```
for x, y in jdictionary.items():
  print(x, y)

17.0 [17.0, 11561.0]
18.0 [18.0, 98640.0, 98641.0]
19.0 [19.0, 98642.0, 131135.0]
20.0 [20.0, 33791.0, 131054.0, 555884.0]
21.0 [21.0, 11562.0, 131241.0]
22.0 [22.0]
23.0 [23.0, 33680.0, 131031.0, 523376.0, 555825.0, 593026.0]
```

Base on dictionary value I want to create a "NewID" field in the pandas dataframe.
If any values in the dictionary match to ID1 and ID2 NewID field should be dictionary key.
It should look like below.

```
    ID1     ID2         NewID
76  21.0    21.0        21.0
77  21.0    11562.0     21.0
78  21.0    131241.0    21.0
79  22.0    22.0        22.0
80  22.0    11562.0     21.0
81  23.0    23.0        23.0
82  23.0    33680.0     23.0
83  23.0    131031.0    23.0
84  23.0    523376.0    23.0
```

Is this possible to do it in a **Lambda** function or any other method?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I updated my answer, please have a look at it and let me know if it is what you want?

Answer (score 1):

If there is no duplicate item within all the items of `jdictionary`, a reverse-lookup dict (`ID2` -> key of `jdictionary`) can be constructed and applied on column `ID2`.

*Edit*: A potential advantage of building up an reverse lookup dictionary is that the dictionary can be passed into `Series.map()`, which uses internally optimized code as indicated by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19798153/difference-between-map-applymap-and-apply-methods-in-pandas/56300992#56300992). But unfortunately, there seems to be no way of avoiding the double `for` loops as indicated in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51654012).

```
# create the reverse lookup dictionary
dic_rev = {}
for k, ls_v in jdictionary.items():
    for v in ls_v:
        dic_rev[v] = k

# optimized execution
df["newID"] = df["ID2"].map(dic_rev)

# output
df
Out[24]: 
     ID1       ID2  newID
76  21.0      21.0   21.0
77  21.0   11562.0   21.0
78  21.0  131241.0   21.0
79  22.0      22.0   22.0
80  22.0   11562.0   21.0
81  23.0      23.0   23.0
82  23.0   33680.0   23.0
83  23.0  131031.0   23.0
84  23.0  523376.0   23.0
```

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

the solution could be:

```
(
    df
    .assign(NewID = lambda x: x.apply(lambda s: 
            next((k for k,v in jdictionary.items() if ((s['ID1'] in v) & (s['ID2'] in v))),np.nan),axis=1))
)
```

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful